# Slow Scraping Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

[image]I am trying to scrape website using selenium.But it is very slow.Taking a minute for every record.

The webpage is https://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/NakalRecord. I'm trying to scrape every record.

So is there any alternative to this,Can i use any api endpoint or HTTPS request

My Code is

```
di=11
district_xpath_new = (By.XPATH, district_xpath)
dropdown_district=Select(handle_stale_element_reference(driver, district_xpath_new))
dropdown_district.select_by_index(di)
total_districts=len(Select(handle_stale_element_reference(driver, district_xpath_new)).options)
while(di<(total_districts)):
    time.sleep(5)
    driver,district_name=district_func(driver,di,district_xpath)
    print("District Started "+str(di))
    te=1
    driver,dropdown_tehsil,total_tehsils,tehsil_name=tehsil_func(driver,te,tehsil_xpath)
#     dropdown_tehsil.select_by_index(te)
    while(te<total_tehsils):
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Tehsil Started is"+str(te))
        driver,dropdown_tehsil,total_tehsils,tehsil_name=tehsil_func(driver,te,tehsil_xpath)
        vi=8
        driver,dropdown_village,total_vill,village_name=village_func(driver,vi,vill_xpath)
        while(vi<total_vill):
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Village Started is"+str(vi))
            driver,dropdown_village,total_vill,village_name=village_func(driver,vi,vill_xpath)
            ye=3
            driver,dropdown_year,total_year,year=year_func(driver,ye,year_xpath)
            while(ye<total_year):
                time.sleep(5)
                print("Year Started is"+str(ye))
                driver,dropdown_year,total_year,year=year_func(driver,ye,year_xpath)
                ow=2
                time.sleep(10)
                print("Selected Personal Ownerlist"+str(ow))
                driver,dropdown_owner=owner_drop(driver,ow,owner_dropdown_xpath)
                name=280
                driver,owner_name_drop,total_names,name_of_owner=owner_names_func(driver,name,owner_name_xpath)
                while(name<total_names):
                    print("Names Started is"+str(name))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    driver,owner_name_drop,total_names,name_of_owner=owner_names_func(driver,name,owner_name_xpath)
                    try:
                        if '?' not in name_of_owner:
                            print(name_of_owner)   
                            df_owner,driver=dataframe_check(driver,district_name,tehsil_name,village_name,year,name)
                            driver=select_all(driver,di,ye,te,vi,ow,name)
                        else:
                            pass
                    except:
                        print("Name is"+str(name))
                        print("Not Found")
                        name+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Selenium has a lot of overhead (Opening the browser, rendering HTML/CSS, javascript, browser again, etc).
Most of the time work done using Selenium can be reduced to a few HTTP requests, which can done directly from Python and way less overhead.

This is essentially that. In web-scraping, browser's Developer Tools are your friend. With a little bit of looking at the Network Tab it can be identified that the webpage makes POST requests to the webserver on each selection to fetch the options for the next category.

It also sends some State Variables to the server. You basically have to emulate that via the `requests` module.

Here is a working example, you can edit it to your needs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


URL = "https://jamabandi.nic.in/land%20records/NakalRecord"


def get_aspnet_form(soup: BS):
    form = {
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__LASTFOCUS": "",
        "__SCROLLPOSITIONX": "0",
        "__SCROLLPOSITIONY": "0",
        "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$a": "RdobtnOwner",
    }

    forms = soup.find("form", attrs={"id": "aspnetForm"})
    for i in forms.find_all("input", recursive=False):
        form.update({i.attrs["name"]: i.attrs["value"]})

    return form


def get_options(soup: BS, type_: str) -> list:
    types = {
        "district": "ddldname",
        "tehsil": "ddltname",
        "village": "ddlvname",
        "period": "ddlPeriod",
        "owner": "ddlOwner",
        "record": "ListBox1",
    }
    ID = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_%s" % types[type_]
    select = soup.find("select", attrs={"id": ID})

    result = []
    for option in select.find_all("option"):
        value = option.attrs["value"]
        text = option.text
        if value != "-1":
            result.append((value, text))

    return [result, select.attrs["name"]]


def get_records(soup: BS):
    ID = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListBox1"
    records = soup.find("select", attrs={"id": ID})

    result = []
    for record in records.find_all("option"):
        name = record.attrs["value"]
        if "?" not in name:
            result.append(name)

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BS(r.content, "html.parser")

    form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
    districts, district_event_target = get_options(soup, "district")
    for district_id, district_name in districts:
        print("Scraping from district %s:" % district_name)
        form["__EVENTTARGET"] = district_event_target
        form[district_event_target] = district_id

        soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

        form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
        tehsils, tehsil_event_target = get_options(soup, "tehsil")
        for tehsil_id, tehsil_name in tehsils:
            print("Scraping from tehsil %s:" % tehsil_name)
            form["__EVENTTARGET"] = tehsil_event_target
            form[district_event_target] = district_id
            form[tehsil_event_target] = tehsil_id

            soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

            form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
            villages, village_event_target = get_options(soup, "village")
            for village_id, village_name in villages:
                print("Scraping from village %s:" % village_name)
                form["__EVENTTARGET"] = village_event_target
                form[district_event_target] = district_id
                form[tehsil_event_target] = tehsil_id
                form[village_event_target] = village_id

                soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

                form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
                periods, period_event_target = get_options(soup, "period")
                for period_id, period_name in periods:
                    print("Scraping from period %s:" % period_name)
                    form["__EVENTTARGET"] = period_event_target
                    form[district_event_target] = district_id
                    form[tehsil_event_target] = tehsil_id
                    form[period_event_target] = period_id

                    soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

                    form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
                    owners, owner_event_target = get_options(soup, "owner")
                    form["__EVENTTARGET"] = owner_event_target
                    form[district_event_target] = district_id
                    form[tehsil_event_target] = tehsil_id
                    form[period_event_target] = period_id
                    form[owner_event_target] = "1"

                    soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

                    records = get_records(soup)
                    print(records)
```

I have made 3 utility functions to help reduce the spaghetti code.
Here is the main loop of the code:

1. Fetch the normal webpage with a `GET` request.
2. Using a HTML tree parser (like `BeautifulSoup`), get the all `district` options.
3. Now get the form variables to be sent using `POST` request
4. Now iterate through each district and send a `POST` request to fetch the webpage concerning that district.
5. Now at each iteration repeat the steps above but for Tehsils
6. Iterate through tehsils to get villages
7. Iterate through Villages to get periods
8. Finally for each period only the `Niji` Owner Records
9. Rinse and repeat until done.

Note 1: For dependencies do `pip install requests bs4`.

Note 2: As a benchmark, each set of records took around `500ms` or `0.5s` to fetch using this method.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for helping.It is really fast
I am also trying to get each nakal,Although i was able to post request for each name and each nakal.
But not sure how to access nakal link which contains main info

Comment: names, name_event_target = get_options(soup, "record")
form = get_aspnet_form(soup)
form["__EVENTTARGET"] = name_event_target
form[district_event_target] = district_id
form[tehsil_event_target] = tehsil_id
form[period_event_target] = period_id
form[village_event_target] = village_id
form[owner_event_target] = "1"
search_new='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtsearch:'
form[search_new]=" "
placeholder_new='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b'
form[placeholder_new]='RdbtnOwner'
form[name_event_target]=names[2][0]
soup = BS(requests.post(URL, data=form).content, "html.parser")

Comment: @jatinrajani I don't see any Nakal Link, so I am not sure.

Comment: Attached screenshot Can you please check

Comment: :Can you please take a look

Comment: You only need Nakal links for the "Niji" category?

Comment: I want to scrape info inside nakal links so a new web page opens want to get that

Comment: @derloopkat can you help here

Comment: @jatinrajani I will look into it tonight.